# sansmath undoes custom mathbb alphabet

Tags: math-fonts, alphabet, blackboard, mathbb, sansmathfonts

I need mathbb symbols for 0 and 1. Currently I'm doing this using the `bbold` fonts. This works great:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mymathbb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\mymathbb{0}
\mymathbb{1} x + y
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image: bbold 01x+y]

However, in another part of my document, I'm using `sansmath`. As soon as I include the sansmath package, the bbold fonts break, even if I don't use sansmath.

[image: 01x+y not in bbold]

How can I get sansmath to stop breaking the other math fonts?

What's odd is it only seems to break for numbers. `mymathbb{N}` works just fine.

Comment: Maybe it would just be easier to lift those two symbols from the font you know has the ones you need: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not quite an answer.)

The offending lines are in `sansmath.sty`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathord}{operators}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathord}{operators}{`1}
...
```

which globally declare `0` and `1` to use the `operators` symbol font.

I don't have a good workaround beyond creating a local copy of `sansmath.sty` in which these lines are commented out. But maybe this will be good enough for you!